# TypeError: language.map is not a function when getting data using axios

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios, material-ui

This is my component here I'm using MUI for table. I'm getting data from API and I also use `map` method to get my data but I'm getting error that says:

```
TypeError: language.map is not a function
```

But when put language in square it does not error but also not show any data on UI according to me my code is correct can anyone help me.

**Language.js**

```
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
 import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Languages = () => {
const [language, setLanguage] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
axios
  .get(
    "https://omxdgcc23c.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/misc/languages? 
 userId=0x60588910"
  )
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
    setLanguage(res.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
 }, []);

 return (
<div>
  <h1>Languages</h1>

  <TableContainer component={Paper}>
    <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>Id</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">English Text</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right"> Text</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">Category</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">Order Index</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">Language Code</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">Created Time</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">Updated Time</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {language.map((languages) => {
          return (
            <TableRow key={languages.id}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {languages.uid}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.engText}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.text}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.category}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.index}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.code}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.createdAt}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.updatedAt}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          );
        })}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
</div>
 );
 };
  export default Languages;
```

Comment: Try replacing `language.map` with `[ ...language ].map`.

Answer (score 1):

See the axios [API](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api) here, the fetched data is also stored in the data property, so you have to access it like this:

```
axios.get('...').then(res => setLanguage(res.data.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of language state, if it is greater than 0 after only you can map the language array,

Kindly, check with below code,

```
{ language && language.length > 0 && language.map((languages) => {
          return (
            <TableRow key={languages.id}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {languages.uid}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.engText}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.text}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.category}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.index}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.code}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.createdAt}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{languages.updatedAt}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          );
 })}
```

Answer (score 0):

The api response is of the format:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "data": [
    {...},
    {...} 
  ]
}
```

So when setting `languages` you need to save the `data` property of the response's `data` object.
`setLanguage(_.get(res, 'data.data', []));`
Then, `languages` will always be a list, and you won't need to check it throughout the rest of your function.

You may need to check the response in your `useEffect` block if you want to do some error handling against a bad api response. But that's now in one place rather than throughout the rest of the function.